# Generating timestamp based documenIds in kafka connect

Tags: apache-kafka, couchbase, apache-kafka-connect

I am sending data from Kafka to Couchbase using kafka sink connector (https://github.com/apache/kafka & https://github.com/couchbase/kafka-connect-couchbase).
I am using CB v5.1.0 and kafka 2.12

I have not enabled any kind of documentId generation in kafka connect (in file quickstart-couchbase-sink.properties). So, the connector is using the whole document as key. I want to generate key as topic-partition-offset-randomString-timestamp.

How can this be achieved? I could find something here - https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/configuration_options.html but I don't see key.ignore option anywhere in kafka and kafka-connect code.

Comment: "confluent kafka" isn't a thing, and kafka-connect is not specific to Confluent. If you are seeing that `transforms` are what you need, then that is what will work

Comment: "the connector is using the whole document as key" The whole document, really? That sounds like a problem with the Elasticsearch source connector. Can you show an example of what the key looks like please?